# Trouble Installing Eclipse Classic 4.2

Tags: java, python, eclipse, installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Eclipse can't find the JDk or JRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419983/eclipse-cant-find-the-jdk-or-jre)

I have the latest JRE and JDK installed, however when I install Eclipse Classic 4.2 and try to run it, it displays the following message:

[image: Eclipse error message]

I have tried moving the installation to Program Files, as well as to the Java installation folder itself. The former generates no difference other than the path displayed in the message. The latter starts loading Eclipse, to the point that it shows the blue rectanglue loading box, at which point I get a different error message saying it couldn't load a particular.dll file in the Java installation. That said, I don't see why I would have to move the Eclipse files into the Java folder for it to work.

I used to have a working installation of Eclipse some time ago, which I uninstalled. Now I plan to use Eclipse, possibly with PyDev, in order to learn Python.

P.S. I realize this is not exactly a question involving coding, however I know I can't be the only one experiencing this issue. So hopefully others may benefit from seeing the response.

EDIT: The installation is now working. Here are the steps I took:

1) Make sure the JDK and Eclipse installations are both 32-bit or 64-bit, depending on your setup.

2) Add `-vm
/absolute/path/to/jre6/bin` to the top of the eclipse.ini file

Note: After reinstalling both Eclipse and the JDK, making sure the bit-type matched, step 2 was no longer necessary as Eclipse finally ran normally.

Comment: See also: http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F#Find_the_JVM

Comment: I've taken a look at these sources, however at best, it leaves me back where I was when I transferred Eclipse to the Java installation. The error I receive now is 'Failed to load the JNI shared library "C:Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\client\jvm.dll".'

Comment: Then please provide your `eclipse.ini` file.

Comment: Also make sure that you're using a 64-bit JDK with a 64-bit bundle of Eclipse, and a 32-bit JDK with a 32-bit bundle of Eclipse.

Comment: I'm currently exploring the avenue mentioned above. I do have a 64-but installation of Windows 7, however the two default program folders I have are 'Program Files' and 'Program Files (x86)'. So I should be installing the 64-bit version of the JDK, not the 86-bit?

Comment: By default, the 32-bit JDK will install into "Program Files (x86)", and a 64-bit JDK will install into "Program Files".  Under 64-bit Windows, you can choose to use either 32-bit or 64-bit Eclipse/JDK - but the Eclipse bundle and the JDK must match.  (I'd recommend 64-bit, as your OS supports it.)

Comment: Alright, Eclipse is finally working. Maybe now I can continue to learn Python. Thanks to all those who helped. My solution is posted above in the edit.

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked before and the answer was very well written so just follow the link and read the answer to this.

[Eclipse - no Java (JRE) / (JDK) ... no virtual machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030434/eclipse-no-java-jre-jdk-no-virtual-machine)

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

As noted above:

- Please refer to http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F#Find_the_JVM.
- Also make sure that you're using a 64-bit JDK with a 64-bit bundle of Eclipse, and a 32-bit JDK with a 32-bit bundle of Eclipse.
- By default, the 32-bit JDK will install into "Program Files (x86)", and a 64-bit JDK will install into "Program Files". Under 64-bit Windows, you can choose to use either 32-bit or 64-bit Eclipse/JDK - but the Eclipse bundle and the JDK must match. (I'd recommend 64-bit, as your OS supports it.)