# Eclipse unable to find JRE

Tags: eclipse, java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Eclipse can’t find the JDK or JRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419983/eclipse-cant-find-the-jdk-or-jre)

I installed Eclipse Juno 64bit, but eclipse is not running . It is giving me error that it is unable to find jvm.dll and jdk etc. I provided the path to folder where JDK and jre is present in `eclipse.ini` but still I am getting errors and unable to run eclipse.

My JDK and jre are in `C:/Program Files(x86)`

How can I solve this issue?

Regards

Comment: Make sure you have installed your operating system supported version 32bit or 64bit.

Comment: @NimChimpsky I think the problem is to do with starting eclipse itself, not the compiler/JRE settings within it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot run a 64bit Eclipse with a 32bit JVM (32bit software goes to `Program Files(x86)`).

Install a 64bit version of Java or a 32bit version of Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

In the eclipse.ini file, the key is that the -vm entry must come before the -vmargs entry and there is a line break between the -vm argument and your path.

It should be something like:
    -vm
    *absolute_path_to_javaw.exe*/javaw.exe

I believe you can also use java.exe (instead of javaw.exe).

Anything for running eclipse should come before the -vmargs line and anything for the JVM should be after it.

Comment: A space is no problem as long as you either put the path behind the `-vm` without anything else on a single line or the `-vm` on one line and path (without any other option) on the next line.