# How to fix "The code execution cannot proceed because jli.dll was not found. Reinstalling the Program may fix this problem." While installing eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, installation

How can i fix the Error message "The code execution cannot proceed because jli.dll was not found. Reinstalling the Program may fix this problem." while installing eclipse.

[image: Screenshot of the Error message]

After the above Error message, **i copy javaw.exe** as stated here: [A JRE or JDK must be available in order to run Eclipse. No JVM was found after searching the following locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419983/a-jre-or-jdk-must-be-available-in-order-to-run-eclipse-no-jvm-was-found-after-s)

**After pasting the javaw.exe** to the eclipse folder, i Double click the Eclipse.exe to run, the error message below show up
[image: After copying javaw.exe to eclipse folder]

Comment: According to your first screenshot you are using Eclipse Oxygen which is a couple of years and 16 releases behind and which does not work with recent Java versions. Use Eclipse 2022-03 instead.